# NSTextView : how to subclass, override -mouseDown and still be able to select text?

Tags: macos, cocoa, mouseevent, nstextview

I subclassed `NSTextView`. The `.m` is very simple and short :

```
@implementation MyTextView

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"click") ;
}

@end
```

But now, I cannot select text anymore in MyTextView. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [super mouseDown:theEvent];